# Синтаксические ошибки, речевые ошибки

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте! Можно ли сказать: "Он держался безусловным Дон Жуаном"? Или слово "безусловным" неприменимо в подобном предложении и является синтаксической ошибкой? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сочетаемость слов в выражении "безусловный донжуан" вызывает сомнения.

Предлагаемые варианты: "Он держался **настоящим (совершенным)** донжуаном.

**Другие определения,** которые встречаются в текстах: большой, изрядный, неисправимый.

**Пример:** Андреев не вел себя как **завзятый донжуан**, женщины льнули к нему сами. [Татьяна Моспан. Подиум (2000)]

**ЗАВЗЯТЫЙ**,  Разг. Постоянно и с увлечением занимающийся чем-л., отдающийся чему-л. З. шахматист. З. охотник. З. театрал. // **Настоящий, истый**. З. мошенник. З-ая сплетница.

**БЕЗУСЛОВНЫЙ**, 1 2. Не вызывающий никаких сомнений; бесспорный, несомненный. Б-ая удача. Иметь б. авторитет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксической — не является. Наверно, является речевой. Или стилистической.

Comment: Но, в общем, говорить так неправильно, это ошибка?

Comment: Здесь противоречие между подразумеваемой _условностью_, с которой людей именуют донжуанами, и словом "_безусловный_", которым эту условность невольно отменяют.

Comment: Да, я сама об этом думала. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Полностью согласна с отвечающими. Но, если хотите избежать речевой ошибки (ошибки в нарушении лексической сочетаемости слов), можете взять слово "безусловным" в кавычки. И это будет означать, что Вы вложили своё понимание в лексическую наполняемость слова, это будет Ваш собственный авторский неологизм.